# Do predators eat meat in the Kung Fu Panda universe?

Tags: kung-fu-panda

There are a considerable number of predators featured in the various Kung Fu Panda properties including [Tigress](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/Tigress) (a tiger), [Tai Lung](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/Tai_Lung) (a leopard), [Boss Wolf](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/Boss_Wolf) (a wolf) and [Viper](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/Viper) (a snake), to name but a few.

As far as I'm aware, cats, snakes and wolves are *obligate carnivores* in the real world, but they seem to be wholly vegetarian in the Kung Fu Panda films and shows, feeding on noodles, dumplings and veg.

**Do we ever see anyone eating anything that's not vegetarian**?

[image]

Comment: Out of universe theory. A society in manga Beastars which highly ressemble Kung Fu Panda. Predator main food is high calory food. They can eat meat (a.k.a others animals) but they may get addicted and become serial killer.

Comment: Related: [Is meat/fish eaten in the Kung Fu Panda universe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/108593/49)

Comment: @someoneuseless Note that in the real world, animals that are obligate carnivores are so because they can't synthesize some micronutrients which aren't found in large quantities in most plant foods (for cats, mainly taurine) and also because their digestive tracts aren't adapted to extract nutrients from plant matter. It has nothing to do with the calorie content of plant foods vs meat. As a side note, since domestic dogs aren't obligate carnivores, I'd be surprised if wolves are.

Comment: @Vaelus - It's very hard, if not impossible to replicate or replace the nutrients that cats and snakes need to survive, hence why the ASPCA and RSPCA consider trying to make a cat or snake vegan to be illegal cruelty. A diet of noodles, dumplings and vegetables (in particular) would result in their untimely deaths in fairly short order.

Comment: @Valorum I agree; the types of vegetarian diets shown in Kung Fu Panda would be very bad for a cat's health and almost certainly fatal. However, it seems technologically feasible, at least, that *some sort of* fortified vegetarian diet could be created which is healthful for cats, since all of the nutrients they need are either found in, or can be synthesized from plant products. But it would definitely not look anything like a typical human vegetarian diet. I have no idea about snakes though.

Comment: @Vaelus Interestingly one of the main genetic differences between wolves and domestic dogs is that the latter are more able to digest the starch that humans often leave in their waste.

Comment: Anybody else come here looking for "The Predator". That would make an interesting cross-over....

Comment: @Pam - I would watch that

Comment: The same problem was solved in _Madagascar_ by feeding the lion lots of fish.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that traditional Shaolin monk diet is vegetarian. Them not eating meat in the movie may be a nod to that.

Comment: @MishaR - Shaolin warrior monks are allowed to eat meat outside the temple (and historically have done so with gusto).

Answer (score 42):

From [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/110223/45378) on a related question on Movies & TV the answer would be no and that all the characters are vegetarian as explained by John Stevenson.

> Although there’s also a tie-in with McDonald’s, which will offer Happy Meals with toys inside, it should be noted that noodles and tofu are the mainstays of the movie characters’ diets. No carnivores in this cartoon. **"Everybody is vegetarian, even our predatory characters—otherwise it got too weird,"** explains Stevenson.
>
> <sub>[how stuff works, Inside 'Kung Fu' Panda](https://web.archive.org/web/20190929040220/https://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/kung-fu-panda.htm)</sub>

Comment: You want weird? In the VeggieTales series, one of the characters is a talking tomato. Pizza exists in the setting. I'm curious to know what the sauce on the pizza is made from.

Comment: @EvilSnack - Worthy of its own question, perhaps. That being said, I'm seeing [plenty of pizza](https://bigidea.fandom.com/wiki/Pizza) but all with [pepperoni and cheese and bread, but no tomato sauce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=jEUJTo6-stg&app=desktop)

Answer (score 36):

Nothwithstanding [the quote](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/237052/20774) from the co-director of the first film that "*everyone is vegetarian*", there do seem to be **several instances where we see animals prepared and eaten as food**, although this may be a continuity error.

[image]
Grubs are boiled and served in a stew in [KFP:PoD - *Poison in the Pit of Plum*](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/Poison_in_the_Pit_of_Plum)

[image]
King prawns are served 'shell-on' in [KFP:PoD - *A Game of Fists*](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/A_Game_of_Fists)

---

The Dreamworks licenced first-reader book [*Po's Tasty Training*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00134TC4M) shows Po getting ready to eat a range of meat-based foods; Lobster, slug, clam and frog.

[image]

Terrifyingly, the tie-in book *[Kung Fu Panda 2 : Po & Ping's recipe storybook](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21142702-kung-fu-panda-2)* ("*learn how to make some of the Ping family's secret recipes!*") features a wide range of animals *that we know to be intelligent* being eaten, including chicken, pork and beef.

[image]

Comment: +1 but I imagine this is the whole "do these really count as animals?" argument, especially the grubs.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - One of the main characters is a stick-insect.

Comment: Maybe they are just taking a bath.

Comment: @SJuan76 - And the prawns are hanging out by the pool?

Comment: It looks like more like a contest of holding their breath.

Comment: @SJuan76 [apple-bobbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_bobbing).

Comment: @marcellothearcane - Remind me not to come around your house for Halloween

Comment: This can be handwaved away easily by the same consideration my pediatrician apparently holds.  Instructions for our vegetarian child for obtaining protein and iron both were "Make sure to eat fish once a week"... perhaps they consider these small grubs and prawns to be not-meat.

Comment: @SJuan76 And the lemon slice is the judge, right? :D

Comment: @Joe Could also be that the pediatrician has the child's best interest at heart. Young children rarely are vegetarians, but their parents might be...

Comment: @StianYttervik Given this was canned instructions, perhaps, though in this case it's fully the child's choice and both parents are happy carnivores :)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Frogs, chicken, slugs and cows are all animals.

Comment: Nit pick, but most cookbooks in the real world also features dishes containing a wide range of animals that we know to be sentient.

Comment: @Vaelus - I could probably argue the toss about whether animals are sentient but intelligent is probably a better word anyway